# Create array of object as user requirement increase?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, c++11

I would like to know is possible to create arrays as user requires. For example

1. I ask the user "Do you want coffee"
   2.if the user say yes and i create a array of coffee object.
   .....
2. I ask the user "Do you want to have another coffee"?
3. if user say yes than i create another array of coffee class
   if not i dont create.

Is this achieveable or must i create a fixed number of array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create fixed size array at runtime in C++, except some compilers (like g++) provides extension for [VLA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c).

Use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) instead. It grows as per your control and automatically deallocates itself when requirement is done.

**Edit**: As the `std::vector` cannot be used by the asker, following is the way using `new[]` with 'some' pseudo code:

```
Coffee **pQuestions = new Coffee* [n]; // n - number of times coffee is asked
for(uint i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
  /* ask for Coffee */
  if(/* yes */)
    pQuestion[i] = new Coffee[size]; // whatever array size you want
}
```

<sup>Here `n` and `size` are variables(can or cannot be constants) as per your need</sup>

Later when you are done, deallocate all the memory as `delete[] pQuestions[i];` and `delete[] pQuestions;`.

Comment: int * myArray = new int[5];  // creating a fixed-size array at runtime in C++?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, no that's not fixed sized array. It's a dynamic array similar to `std::vector`; only syntactical difference is that `new[]` returns a raw pointer. Internally `std::vector` does `new[]` and lot more things.

Comment: I cant use vector. I need to use array only.

Comment: @iammilind can u explain abit further, sample codes may be please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard container classes like [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) which gives you resizeable vectors of some arbitrary but given type. Of course, you can have vectors of vectors, or vectors of queues, etc.

<sup>(You could use manually allocated pointers and code à la C, but you'll better use the powerful containers provided by the STL).</sup>